# Brackets for Live edge wood shelf

Tags: brackets, shelf

I have a wood shelf I want to hang in my kitchen. The description states 8 x 24 however; the shelf is actually 9" on one end and 8" on the other end. I understand the brackets should be 1" shorter than the depth. Would it be ok to use two 7" brackets? I know the best bet is to drill into the stud and of course would do that if possible or use anchors. I anticipate putting a few dishes, spice bottles and something decorative on the shelf. Nothing too heavy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using two brackets is fine.  The brackets do not necessarily need to be 1 inch shorter than the shelf unless the manufacturer says so.  If you hit multiple studs and use hardened construction screws, the weakest part of a floating shelf is the bracket welds. My kitchen has four 2” x 11” x 48” shelves with 36” x 6” brackets and they are rated to a static load of 150 lbs.  I’ve never had any issue with all the stoneware dishes I keep on it.

Answer (score 0):

Curious as to the difference in size.

Yes, the 7" brackets would be OK. You need to screw into the studs for the most secure mounting. If that's not possible, use anchors similar to the ones shown below or toggle bolts. People always say "nothing too heavy" and then a few months later, they're back on this site asking how to repair a wall that shelf brackets pulled out of. Also, never hurts to put a few small screws through the bracket up into the shelf to hole it steady.

Comment: Thanks very much. It is kinda unusual for it to be 2 different lengths. I really wanted a live edge shelf and came across this one and really like it. Will definitely try for drilling into studs and it can't be done, use the proper bolts. I know the brackets come with anchors/toggles but not sure if the same as what you suggest. Will take a look. Thanks for responding.